# CFileDialog delayed crashing

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have added an "Open file" dialog to my dialog-based MFC application. Now, exactly one minute(!) after an open file dialog is closed by pushing either Open or Cancel button my application crashes. While it crashes, the following things are happening in the output:

1) a bunch of Windows threads are exiting;

2) a bunch of COM exceptions (of 0x80010108 "the object invoked has disconnected from its clients" and 0x800401FD "Object is not connected to server" variety) are being thrown;

3) finally, an unhandled exception occurs: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeefeee, with call stack pointing to ole32.dll.

To say that I am bewildered is quite an understatement. The code for invoking the dialog is as follows:

```
CFileDialog fileDlg( TRUE, _T(".txt"), NULL, OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST, 
                     _T("Text file (*.txt)|*.txt||"), this);
INT_PTR res = fileDlg.DoModal();
```

What could cause such a thing?

How do I even debug it?

Comment: Have you commented out EVERYTHING after the dialog close, to ensure it really is the dialog causing this, and not some operation working on its result?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer - yep, nothing is happening.

Comment: We once had a similar problem. Our app crashed on certain actions done inside a file open dialog. The cause was a buggy Windows Shell Extension DLL (Adobe Acrobat Reader Preview), which was hard to track down. Can you reproduce the problem on a clean Windows system?

Comment: @Aesthete - it really is not much help: 
ole32.dll!74c5c99e()    
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ole32.dll]   
ole32.dll!74c9eb7f()
ole32.dll!74c9eb4d()  
...
fundisc.dll!5c4f63ee()  
kernel32.dll!764d339a()  

etc.

Comment: @FrankBollack - everything appears to work fine on a colleague's PC. How did you track down the exact culprit, anyways?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't released a COM object somewhere, or if you have something went wrong. 0xfeeefeee is used to mark free'd heap memory, so maybe something has been released and then used again?

Comment: @Aesthete - Well yeah, that appears to be the case, the problem is I don't use any COM objects =)

Comment: @obamator: In our special case, we realised after some trail and error(crash) that the problem only happend when we moved the mouse cursor over a PDF file and that this was only the case on some PCs, especially in our testing environment. Solution was, not to fix it, as also other applications showed exactly the same behaviour.

Comment: You can get a better stack by right clicking on an unknown stack entry and selecting to download symbol information. (assuming this is a newer version of visual studio anyways)

Comment: I’ve seen the same problem with CFileDialog in VS 2010 SP1 on Windows Server 2008 R2 but only when I was running the MFC app in the debugger (F5).  When I “Start Without Debugging” (Ctrl+F5) or just run the EXE the delayed crash does not happen.  I haven’t been able to figure out why that is though.

Comment: Same problem here: crash in Visual Studio one minute after you have used the open file dialog in debuggee. Stack is only 1 entry long. We suspect a shell extension as well, but which one, since all this RPC stuff seems asynchronous...

Comment: I had this problem too. The cause was I was using UI Automation on the main thread of the application. I took it out to another thread and everything worked fine since then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this *exact* issue in Windows 7 x64, and by enabling breakpoints on all Win32 exceptions not already chosen (in the VS2015 exceptions tab), I was able to narrow it down to a known issue with fundisc.dll that was resolved with an optional Hotfix from Microsoft: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2494427

It also resolved issues on my PC of File Explorer windows crashing at seemingly random times.  All were caused by some deadlock in the networking COM objects that is fixed by that hotfix.